# Redeploy war on tomcat live productive server

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, war

I have a war which I deployed on a productive tomcat server. Now I have made another updated war which I want to deploy on the server in the place of the old war. I know I can just replace the old war with the new war, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without breaking the application for the users?

Note: I am using a Jenkins script for deploying the war

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Load Balance or Cluster, you can use the [Blue Green deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) methodology.